# Why don't the effects of my Ruby `for` loop persist?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to put all unique combinations of a number's individual digits into an array. I'm passing in an integer and then using the permutation method. But to do so I believe I need to convert the number argument into a string. However when I iterate through the array, it is not joining the strings such that I can convert to an integer. Also I realize I should be using `each` to do the loop and not `for` but not sure how to do this in the block.

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  combo = []
  combo = number.to_s.split("").permutation.to_a
  for i in combo
    i.join.to_i
  end
  return combo
end
```

Is there something wrong with my loop? When I test one item in the array using `combo[0].join.to_i` I get an integer as output. But for some reason my loop is leaving these as strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example attempt, you failed to modify the contents of the array. I've replaced your `for` loop with a call to `Array#map`, which has a return value of a new Array containing the results of each iteration in order. Here is a verbose version of the method you want (for clarity).

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  permutations = number.to_s.split('').permutation

  numbers = permutations.map do |digits|
    digits.join.to_i
  end

  return numbers
end

number_shuffle 123 # => [123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321]
```

If you prefer a one-liner (replacing `split` with `chars`, per @timbetimbe below):

```
def number_shuffle(n)
  n.to_s.chars.permutation.map {|x| x.join.to_i }
end
```

Comment: The explicit return (and the last assignment for that matter) is unnecessary.

Comment: I get it. There is also value in writing idiomatic  code.

Comment: Added that additional one liner that leverages `chars` and negates `to_a` after my post. Nice.

Comment: @JesseSielaff yeah, I realized that I forgot to answer the question, and no you didn't. you _just_ removed the final one, and the use of `chars`... anyways. Good show.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your `for` loop does not mutate `combo` is because it does nothing to it. The interpreter just evaluates `i.join.to_i` but does not edit the value in place.

Secondly, you do not need to use `for`, `return`, `split('')` or `to_a` on the return from `permutation` as they are not really idiomatic approaches. A more concise approach would be:

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  number.to_s.chars.permutation.map { |combo| combo.join.to_i }
end
```

Reasoning:

- favor `each` over `for` as it's preferred in the community.
- use `map` from `permutation` as it includes `Enumerable` (same as `Array`) so you can just jump right into `map`
- `returns` are implicit, embrace that :)

Linters help tremendously when getting started: [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop)

This style guide is enforced by: [bbatsov's Style Guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)

Answer (score 1):

Even faster and more efficient (to not have to copy anything in memory):

```
def number_shuffle(number)
  number.to_s.split('').permutation.to_a.map do |combination|
    combination.join.to_i
  end
end
```